# How to send message a list with foreach only one message

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a message with one list with PHP, here is my code:

```
$packs = $db->QueryFetchArrayAll("SELECT * FROM configmoreg");

foreach($packs as $pack) {
    echo '<a>'.$pack['setting_id'].'</a>
        <a>'.$pack['config_name'].'</a>
        <a>'.$pack['config_value'].'</a>
        <br>';
}

mail('example@something.com',"My List",$msg);
```

How do I make it send only one message with list on it?

For example:

> 1. id 00000001
> 2. My_name game_over_new
> 3. NR_Job 11
> 4. type_secure MD5
>
> 5 etc...

Comment: You need to concatenate a string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try adding all the variables to an array; then send the array containing the variables.

As you don't know how to use arrays I suggest reading:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

However to get what you want, you'll want something along these lines:

```
$infoToSend = array($pack['setting_id'], $pack['config_name'], $pack['config_value']);

mail('example@something.com',"My List", $infoToSend);
```

Comment: i don't know how to attach all in array with \n (Newline)

Comment: is not working somehow i tried, and about negative vote i didn't cus i can't vote unti get reput 15

Answer (score 0):

Build up a string in the `for-loop`, and send *that*.  Consider:

```
$msg = '';
foreach($packs as $pack)
  $msg .= "<a>${pack['some_key']}</a>";

$subject = "My List";
mail('null@example.com', $subject, $msg);
```

Meanwhile, I gather you're still learning PHP, so hold on to this next piece of advice until you're ready: don't use PHP's builtin `mail()` function, use [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).